# Not enough input arguments error being shown for a system of 2 first order ODEs

Tags: matlab

I am trying to simulate a system of two 1st order ODEs in Matlab but I keep getting an error which says "not enough input arguments in line 3". I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please enlighten me so I can run the code?

```
function xdot = eqx2(t,x);
xdot = zeros(2,1);
xdot(1) = x(2);
xdot(2) = sin(4.3*t) - 16*x(1);
[t,x] = ode45('eqx2', [0,2*pi], [0,0]);
plot(t,x(:,1),t,x(:,2),'--'), xlabel('t'),axis([0 2*pi -3 3])
plot(x(:,1),x(:,2)), xlabel('x1'), ylabel('x2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function handle to the function eqx2 when calling ode45:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@eqx2, [0,2*pi], [0,0]);

subplot(211)
plot(t, x(:,1), t,x(:,2),'--');
xlabel('t')

subplot(212)
plot(x(:,1), x(:,2))
xlabel('x1')
ylabel('x2')

function xdot = eqx2(t,x)
  xdot = zeros(2,1);
  xdot(1) = x(2);
  xdot(2) = sin(4.3*t) - 16*x(1);
end
```

Also, in your code, your function implementation included, incorrectly, the call to `ode45` itself and your second plot was overwriting the first one.

[image]

As a best practice, define your local functions at the bottom of your MATLAB script and close them with an `end` statement:

```
function foo1
  ...
end

<more functions here> 

function fooN
  ...
end
```